# How do I print a line of a shell-script in a shell-script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that executes a command with a bunch of arguments that are, themselves, constructed by the script.

Eg. the script contains a line like this

```
do $opts x y z $more_opts a b c "bit in quotes" $stuff
```

I'd like to print out what this line actually is.

If I try :

```
echo 'do $opts x y z $more_opts a b c "bit in quotes" $stuff'
```

then I get the line with $opts and $more_opts being quoted literally rather than expanded into their values.

If I try backticks :

```
echo `do $opts x y z $more_opts a b c "bit in quotes" $stuff`
```

then it executes the line itself.

How can I generate and print a version of this string, with the $opts expanded into their values, but unexecuted?

Comment: Very often, `(set -x; cmd $opts x y z $more_opts a b c "bit in quotes" $stuff)` works.  It doesn't work if the use of a sub-shell interferes with something — but for a direct command invocation, it works.  The use of `do` in the question is suspect; it is a keyword in some contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most accurate is:

```
printf '%q ' $opts x y z $more_opts a b c "bit in quotes" $stuff ; echo
```

since it will do the same word-splitting, filename-globbing, etc., as your actual command. (For example, if `$stuff` is `*`, this version will correctly list all the files in your directory, since that's what your real command will do.)

(Hat-tip to Gordon Davisson for suggesting `printf` + `%q`, so the final resulting arguments get re-quoted, instead of just printing them as-is.)

A better approach, though, might be what Jonathan Leffler suggests above:

```
(set -x; cmd $opts x y z $more_opts a b c "bit in quotes" $stuff)
```

which will tell Bash to debug-print the command before running it. That way you don't need to update your `echo` command every time you update your actual command.

Comment: This won't *quite* work if any filename globs expand to anything containing spaces and/or glob metacharacters. If this is a potential issue *and* you're using bash (not a generic POSIX shell), it can be fixed by using e.g. `echo do"$(printf " %q" $opts)" x y z ...`. Yeah, it's icky, but it'll do the job.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: I don't see it. Why won't this work in that case? The globs should only be processed once.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Oh, wait, I see. You're picturing that the OP will want to copy-and-paste the printed command and be able to run it. (Or at least, that (s)he'll want to be able to tell with confidence from the printed command where one argument ends and the next begins.) OK, yeah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

While the solutions outlined here work, I would strongly advice against doing it, because a statement of the form

```
echo myprog $foo $bar $baz
myprog $foo $bar $baz
```

creates a maintenance problem: Whenever you modify the `myprog ....` line, you have to update the `echo ....` line in the same way.

A better solution would be to define a function

```
function echorun {
  printf "EXECUTING:" # You can leave this out, if you want to
  printf " %q" "$@" # Thank you, Gordon Davisson
  echo # Supplying final newline
  "$@"
}
```

and run the commands which you are wanting to log, with

```
echorun do $opts x y z $more_opts a b c "bit in quotes" $stuff
```